# When does autoexec.sas execute

Tags: sas

In this [SAS tutorial](http://www.pauldickman.com/teaching/sas/autoexec.php)

```
AUTOEXEC.SAS is processed once, when the SAS application is started
```

I am confused about the term SAS application. When I installed SAS, it came with many components like Di studio, OLAP studio , Management console, SAS enterprise guide. Will the autoexec.sas execute when any of these components start up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is talking about the `sas.exe` process; when that runs. `autoexec.sas` is processed.  That may occur multiple times if you have a server that spawns multiple processes (or even you instruct Enterprise Guide to do so locally).

Comment: Thanks. Will sas.exe run when I start any SAS product (e.g Managemetn console). I am trying to udnerstand when the sas.exe runs

Comment: SAS.exe is the module that actually runs SAS code (ie, equivalent to `gcc` in the unix C world).  It gets called any time you ask SAS to do something that requires compiling and running actual SAS code (whether code you wrote or code generated from an action).